# I would like to return part of object which has object array inside in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains object arrays as sub-properties.
However, I only want to return part of the object. For example,

My original object is:

```
var  deptObj= 
{
  "requestId": 0,
  "requestId_string": "0",
  "departmentRequests": [
     {
        "persistenceVersion": 3,
        "department": [
             {
               "persistenceId": 111,         
               "persistenceVersion": 0,
               "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
               "userId": 26,
               "userId_string": "26",
               "requestId": 0,
               "requestId_string": "0",
               "deptStatus": "PENDING",
               "groupName": "Group 1 ",
               "groupID": "15",
               "userName": "user",
               "userFirstname": "user1",
               "userLastname": "User",
               "requestDate": "2020-03-26",
               "activityName": "Decision",
               "countPending": 0 
             }
           ],
        "decision": [],
        "comment": "start",
        "approved": [],
        "docIndex": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, I want to get some part of the object. for example,

```
{
  "requestId": 0,
  "departmentRequests": [
     {
        "department": [
          {
            "requestId": 0,
            "groupID": "15",
            "requestDate": "2020-03-26",
            "deptStatus": "PENDING",
             "userId": "26",
             "countPending": 0
          }
        ],
        "comment": "start",
        "docIndex": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to create JavaScript as follows:

```
obj = [];

for(var i in deptObj) {  
    for(var j in deptObj[i].department) {  
    var thisObj = {};   
    thisObj.requestDate = deptObj[i].department[j].requestDate; 
    thisObj.userId =  deptObj[i].department[j].userId; 
    thisObj.deptStatus = deptObj[i].department[j].deptStatus ;
    thisObj.activityName = deptObj[i].department[j].activityName;  
    thisObj.countPending = deptObj[i].department[j].countPending; // 
    obj.push(thisObj);            
   }   
}

//return obj;

return  {
  "requestId": deptObj.requestId, 
  "departmentRequests":  obj 
};
```

I have no idea how to get a sub-array in an object. 
Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the final object result that you want to return?

Comment: I want to return some parts of the object. it is on the body of the question. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over each of the arrays in your objects and extract the desired pieces of data:

```js
var deptObj = {
  "requestId": 0,
  "requestId_string": "0",
  "departmentRequests": [{
    "persistenceVersion": 3,
    "department": [{
      "persistenceId": 111,
      "persistenceVersion": 0,
      "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
      "userId": 26,
      "userId_string": "26",
      "requestId": 0,
      "requestId_string": "0",
      "deptStatus": "PENDING",
      "groupName": "Group 1 ",
      "groupID": "15",
      "userName": "user",
      "userFirstname": "user1",
      "userLastname": "User",
      "requestDate": "2020-03-26",
      "activityName": "Decision",
      "countPending": 0
    }],
    "decision": [],
    "comment": "start",
    "approved": [],
    "docIndex": 0
  }]
}

// get department requests
const reqs = deptObj.departmentRequests.map(function(dr) {
  return {
    "comment": dr.comment,
    "docIndex": dr.docIndex,
    "department": dr.department.map(function(d) {
      return {
        "requestId": d.requestId,
        "groupID": d.groupID,
        "requestDate": d.requestDate,
        "deptStatus": d.deptStatus,
        "userId": d.userId,
        "countPending": d.countPending
      };
    })
  };
});

const res = {
  "requestId": deptObj.requestId,
  "departmentRequests": reqs
};

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in short your object can be used as an array it is just that instead of using indexes(0,1,2,3) you use strings ("myfirstelement","mysecondelement","mythirdelement") but you can change that with :

```
Object.keys()
```

you just take your object and give it to Object.keys() then you can use all the array functions that exist in javascript for instance slice:

[slicing mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

this might give yous something like :

```js
let obj = {"something1":"hello","something1":"hi","something2":"greetings","something3":"how are you","something4":"hello","something5":"hello"};

let subarr = Object.keys(obj).slice(2,4);
 
console.log(subarr);
```

or object.values depending on what you're looking for :

```js
let obj = {"something1":"hello","something1":"hi","something2":"greetings","something3":"how are you","something4":"hello","something5":"hello"};

    let subarr = Object.values(obj).slice(2,4);
     
    console.log(subarr);
```

Comment: Object is NOT an Array. This answer is very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

To return parts of an object, you can do [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
//This basically extracts the values you want
const {requestId, departmentRequests} = deptObj;
// requestId and departmentRequests are now variables containing values from deptObj
```

Based on what you're trying to do:

```
const newObj = {};
newObj.requestId = requestId //the variable we extracted
newObj.departmentRequests = departmentRequests

//We should always avoid referencing the original array by making a copy
//However, because of the next step below which uses map(), we don't worry
//because map() returns a new array;
```

When working with arrays containing objects, to return an array containing only parts of each object, you'll want to use [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

Again, based on what you're trying to do:

```
newObj.departmentRequests.map(department => {
//return an object only containing the parts we want
  return {
    requestId: department.requestId,
    groupID: department.groupID,
    requestDate: department.requestDate,
    deptStatus: department.deptStatus,
    userId: department.userId,
    countPending: department.countPending
  }
})
```

You should now see `newObj` containing what you're trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand Object structures.

```js
const deptObj = {
  "requestId": 0,
  "requestId_string": "0",
  "departmentRequests": [
    {
      "persistenceVersion": 3,
      "department": [
        {
          "persistenceId": 111,
          "persistenceVersion": 0,
          "persistenceVersion_string": "0",
          "userId": 26,
          "userId_string": "26",
          "requestId": 0,
          "requestId_string": "0",
          "deptStatus": "PENDING",
          "groupName": "Group 1 ",
          "groupID": "15",
          "userName": "user",
          "userFirstname": "user1",
          "userLastname": "User",
          "requestDate": "2020-03-26",
          "activityName": "Decision",
          "countPending": 0
        }
      ],
      "decision": [],
      "comment": "start",
      "approved": [],
      "docIndex": 0
    }
  ]
}
const resObj = {
  requestId: deptObj.requestId,
  departmentRequest: deptObj.departmentRequests.map(a=>{
    return {
      department: a.department.map(d=>{
        return {
          requestId: d.requestId,
          groupId: d.groupID,
          requestDate: d.requestDate,
          deptStatus: d.deptStatus,
          userId: d.userId,
          countPending: d.countPending
        }
      }),
      comment: a.comment,
      docIndex: a.docIndex
    }
  })
};
console.log(resObj);
```

Comment: This will only work if there is only one element in the `departmentRequest` and `department` arrays.

Comment: Fixed for @Nick... but really, I wasn't sure that all Objects weren't the same since OP gave us an Object, that was not an Array, to start with.